# Can I use a permanent disability certificate as photo ID for a domestic flight in India?

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, india, domestic-travel, identity-cards

I have a permanent disability certificate; it's a photo ID. Can I take a domestic flight in India with only this ID?

Answer (score 4):

According to the Bureau of Civil Aviation Security, India, the Disability certificate issued by Government is a valid identification document for domestic flights.

Reference: http://www.bcasindia.nic.in/law/AC%2015-2017-listofidproof.pdf